# Mysql workbench refresh EER Diagram from server

Tags: mysql-workbench, database-schema, eer-model

is it possible to refetch or reimport a whole database structure from a server in mysql workbench?

I've tried the synchronize options (both Model and any source), but it always works the other way round (workbench->server) and drops new columns which i've created online / outside of mysql workbench..

i'm using the latest version 5.2.41.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest version 5.2.42 and do a "Database > Synchronize with Any Source"  because it appears that you are still experiencing this bug
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61211

Answer (score 0):

At the step "Select changes to Apply", default it "Update source" (you see the arrow from Left->Right). In your case, you should select the tables and click "Update Model", it will sync from Mysql to Model.